# Whats the fault in the logic I am thinking for not balancing of a needle and any blade etc. on water?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, surface-tension

As we know that contact angle of water with any surface is approximately zero, so why a blade or a needle floats on water as such surface tension can only provide force parallel to the water surface which will not have any vertical component to balance weight, I think I am confusing perhaps the contact angle with angle made by surface tension with water surface but I think its zero . So shouldnt the forces be always parallel to surface ? **As we can see in the below figure here as water is perfectly wetting liquid so theta= 0 ° , so shouldnt phi angle to be zero degree as its the contact angle? Or is the contact angle different here ? Or phi is not the contact angle ?** [image]

Comment: "*As we know that contact angle of water with any surface is approximately zero*" This is patently false. Have you never seen a water drop on a surface?

Answer (score 1):

Surface tension points diagonally up around the depression caused by the needle. Weight points down. Vertical components of surface tension plus weight sum to zero. Horizonal components of surface tension are equal and opposite, so sum to zero. Zero net force on the needle means no acceleration of the needle, so if it starts out at rest on the surface, it remains at rest on the surface.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: The diagram for the flat floating wafer edited into the OP is incorrect. As diagrammed, with the contact surface of the water touching the vertical surfaces of the wafer, that wafer will indeed sink.

Since even the sharpest right angle edges are curved if you zoom in closely enough, the wafer sitting on the water will look something like this.

[image]

As with the needle, the surface of the water is continuous with the bottom surface of the object resting on the water. If we zoom in very closely on the edge, it will look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Let me add a bit more what i meant Sir , can you please see once more ?

Comment: My confusion is regardinf contact angle and that phi angle , the difference is what i want to clarify

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer I have edited my answer in reply.

Comment: If the wafer is perfectly wettable, why doesn't it sink? The interface right angle you've drawn on the sides is unstable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by perfectly wettable, but I think you've defined it to mean zero surface tension, in which case your inference about what that would mean is correct - but obviously inapplicable to water or any other liquid. I think you've defined water to have zero surface tension, then become confused as to how water exhibits the consequences of surface tension. [continued]

Comment: Surface tension corresponds to the free energy per unit area of phase interface. If we zoom in on the sides of the wafer, we see that any shape other than one whose tangent is continuous with the bottom of the wafer would increase the area of the water-gas interface. This constitutes an increase in energy, therefore it takes work to move towards such a state and the system will do work moving away from such a state. Therefore the curve whose tangent is continuous with the bottom of the wafer (or other object resting on the surface) is the *only* stable configuration.

Comment: Granted there's no such thing as a true right angle edge in nature, so if we zoom in very, very closely on the wafer, we will find that the edges are bumpy and rounded and that the water's curve conforms to that bumpy, rounded tangent shape.

Comment: @Chemomechanics interface right angle which i have drawn Sir ? If yes its not at right angle its at phi angle with horizontal .

Comment: @gs Sir in the first picture you posted can you show the angle of 0° contact made by water ? I seems to not see how its making that angle

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer I phrased that badly, I should have said that the angle of contact was continuous with the shape of the needle, not that it was 0 degrees. I will edit.

Comment: Sure but **shouldnt angle of contact for any pair of liquid-solid is a constant** ?

Comment: So why it will vary continuously?

Comment: Actually, I think I've messed up the last picture by neglecting the reality of microscopic curvature. I will have to delete that part and edit. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: “*I'm not sure what you mean by perfectly wettable, but I think you've defined it to mean zero surface tension,*” The standard definition, rather, is that the contact angle is nearly 0°, as specified in the original question. My question is why you’ve drawn the sides of the wafer as staying dry somehow when wetting of these surfaces would occur spontaneously while providing the energy benefit of allowing the wafer to sink lower. I never said anything about zero surface tension.

Comment: @Chemomechanics do my edits correct my mistake in your assessment?

Comment: "Perfectly wettable" $=$ hydrophilic. That trick will work a whole lot better if the surface of the needle is hydro _phobic._

Comment: @gs This looks better, thank you.